# facing issue while configuring apache Hive1.0 with apache hadoop1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, hive

Facing below mentioned permission issues while running hive in terminal after configuring in .bashrc file.

```
hadoop@hadoop:~$ hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/hadoop/Downloads/apache-hive-1.0.0/lib/hive-common-1.0.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx--x--x
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:444)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:626)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:570)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx--x--x
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:529)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:478)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:430)
... 7 more
```

Comment: Why -1 voting for this question ? Anything wrong in this question ?

Comment: Your question is being down voted, because the error stack clearly shows the issue is with the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue, and nothing related to bashrc file. Give proper permissions to /tmp directory in HDFS and you should be fine.

You can use

```
hadoop fs -chmod [-R] <permissions> <directory>
```

Comment: where the /tmp file located. I did not given any file/folder name as '/tmp' explicitly.

Comment: :- I had given " hadoop fs -chmod [-R] 755 /tmp/hive " command. But still it is giving same error.

Comment: Who is the owner of the directory ? Remove square brackets while using the command. R is for recursive